# 17 gallon pot for rose bush

Tags: container-gardening, roses

I have a 17" tall / 17 gallon pot and I plan to use it for planting my David Austin rose Charles Darwin

https://www.davidaustinroses.com/products/charles-darwin

I know the website said large Shrub but I am wondering if I can contain the root in 17 gallon pot without killing it.

Thought?

Comment: What part of the world?  Is the location where it will be full sun or ??

Comment: @kevinskio The OP's profile says Seattle. (And in any case, only one country in the world uses archaic units like gallons to measure the size of plant pots.)